# Formatar query em linq para enviar para a ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Fiz uma query em linq, mas o resultado não foi o esperado, parece simples o problema mas não consigo resolver.

Resultado na label:

> { Ano = 2016/2017 }

Resultado esperado na label:

> 2016/2017

Controlador:

```
//query
     var queryAnoPastoral = (from a in db.AnoPastoral
                                        orderby a.AnoPastoralID descending
                                        select new { a.Ano }).First();

       ViewBag.AnoPastoral = queryAnoPastoral.ToString();
```

View:

```
@Html.Label((string)@ViewBag.AnoPastoral, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você quer retornar apenas o valor do Ano certo? A forma que você fez você retorna um objeto anônimo por isso quando usa o `.toString()` ele vem com as chaves, você pode alterar sua query pra retornar o Ano direto que vai funcionar da forma que você espera.

```
var queryAnoPastoral = (from a in db.AnoPastoral
                        orderby a.AnoPastoralID descending
                        select a.Ano).First();

ViewBag.AnoPastoral = queryAnoPastoral.ToString();
```